# Cannot install libpng*?

Tags: 14.04, apt, software-installation, libpng

(this blocks the installation of the R package 'png')

When I do:

```
sudo apt-get install libpng*
```

I get:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package libpng12-0_1.2.50-1ubuntu2.14.04.2_amd64.deb
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'libpng12-0_1.2.50-1ubuntu2.14.04.2_amd64.deb'
```

How to install all of `libpng`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`libpng*` does not mean what you think it means for two reasons:

1. The shell expanded it to be `libpng12-0_1.2.50-1ubuntu2.14.04.2_amd64.deb` because there was a file of that name in your current directory.
2. Even if the shell hadn't expanded it, `apt-get` would take it as a regular expression. So, it will install any packaging containing `libpn` in the name.

You might want to do:

```
sudo apt-get install libpng12-dev
```

Comment: I think 2. is what I have been advised to  [do](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35902290/189035). Can it be done?

Comment: @user2413 I think `libpng12-dev` is sufficient (as also indicated by the other user). If you really need to, you can do `sudo apt-get install 'libpng*'` - note the quotes.

Comment: actually, the quotes *were* necessary: it added 600k of software which solved the problem!